# Link subscriber info from CloudPage 1 to CloudPage 2

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, smart-capture

I created 2 landing pages, each with a smartcapture form. I want to not only link the landing pages, but to also ensure that the subscriber from page 1 is passed over to page 2.

Here is what I have done.

In my email a CTA directs to the landing page
 `%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(4499,'Member_Number',@MemberNumber))=%%`

In landing page 1 I do the following

1. pull in the member number `SET @MemberNumber = QueryParameter('Member_Number')`
2. in the form submission cta I use the concat function so that the member number is pushed to page 2 on submit

```
SET @URL = ConCat('https://mydomain?&member=',@member_number,'&email=',@EMAIL)
```

3. in the smartcapture HTML I set the value of onSubmitShouldGotoUrl to `"onSubmitShouldGotoUrl": %%=v(@URL)=%%` - because changing the URL in the UI does not work

In landing page 2 I then retrieve the value that is passed into the page 1 url

```
%%[ SET @Member_Number = QueryParameter('Member_Number')]%%
```

This approach isn't working, in fact when I press submit on landing page 1, I am not taken to page 2.

Instead I am redirected to the same url, but with parameters that contain the value of my smartcapture form field names `https://mydomain?Entry_1=&Entry_2=&Entry_3=Selection+1&Entry_4=`

Answer (score 0):

You could add the data from your variables to hidden form fields, so they will automatically be passed on to the target of your form (landing page 2).

In your example with the member number it would look like this:

AMPscript code:

```
SET @MemberNumber = RequestParameter('Member_Number')
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="%%=v(@MemberNumber)=%%" name="MemberNumber" id="MemberNumber" />
```

And on Landing Page 2 you can retrieve it using

```
SET @MemberNumber = RequestParameter('MemberNumber')
```

Comment: I've given this a try and unfortunately the membernumber is not being retrieved. I have put the HTML code in smart capture > HTML editor